# VBA - How to delete and keep some data with criteria faster

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask if there is a better way to make this code faster because I have data almost 100K rows and this code works pretty slow. Here is the details

We have two days data, A and B which are contained in the column U, one of these days is always one day later than the other.

I find the earlyDay suppose It's A and when a row contains A I want to check if the column S contains certain values, if yes then delete the row. On the other hand if the day in column U is B, then I want to keep only the rows where S has that certain values and delete all the others.

```
Sub D( )
    Dim earlyDay As Date
    earlyDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("u:u"))

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "U").Value = earlyDay Then
            Select Case Cells(i, "S").Value
                Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                    Cells(i, "U").EntireRow.Delete
            End Select
        Else
            Select Case Cells(i, "S").Value
                Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                Case Else
                    Cells(i, "S").EntireRow.Delete
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a general sort order or is the data random? How many columns of data total?

Comment: hey thanks for responding, it’s a general sorted data and have around 25 columns in total

Comment: Sorry, I had an idea on how to proceed (tested 100K records with ~50% deleted in 4 seconds) but it is based on a certain type of data structure. If you don't know how many columns you have then it isn't going to work.

Comment: Sorry, well there are 25 columns in total.

Comment: If you use Autofilter + Loop then your code will run much faster :)

Comment: Or you can transfer the data to an array and work with the array. That is ever more faster than Autofilter + Loops

Comment: Quick question `earlyDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("u:u"))` this is for "Early Day". How are you calculating "Later Day"?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth! I might have to find out how. and well supposing you got early day then "Else" is later day because there are only 2 days data :)

Comment: I have posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see my answer.

Comment: Hey I got it, really appreciate it Siddharth. and Thanks to everyone who have tried to help me find out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

You mentioned that

1. You have 25 columns
2. For early day, if the `Col U = Early Day` and `Col S = AAA,BBB or CCC` then delete it
3. For later day, if the `Col U = Early Day` and `Col S <> AAA,BBB or CCC` then delete it
4. later day is 1 day greater than early day.

If the above is correct then your data, after deleting, will look like this

[image]

As I mentioned in the comment below your post that using array will be faster, I am going to use that approach.

Try this code. I have commented the code so you will not have a problem understanding it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim earlyDay As Date, laterDay As Date
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rng As Range, delRange As Range
    Dim tmpArray As Variant

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row of column U
        lRow = .Range("U" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your Early and Later day here
        earlyDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(.Range("U1:U" & lRow))
        laterDay = DateAdd("d", 1, earlyDay)

        '~~> Identify your range
        Set rng = .Range("A1:Y" & lRow)

        '~~> Transfer it to array
        tmpArray = rng.Value

        '~~> Loop through the array and clear unnecessary rows
        For i = LBound(tmpArray) To UBound(tmpArray)
            If tmpArray(i, 21) = earlyDay Then
                Select Case tmpArray(i, 19)
                Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                    For j = 1 To 25
                        tmpArray(i, j) = ""
                    Next j
                End Select
            ElseIf tmpArray(i, 21) = laterDay Then
                Select Case tmpArray(i, 19)
                Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                Case Else
                    For j = 1 To 25
                        tmpArray(i, j) = ""
                    Next j
                End Select
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Clear Sheet for pasting new output
        .Cells.ClearContents

        '~~> Transfer data from array to worksheet
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(tmpArray), 25).Value = tmpArray

        '~~> Find new last row
        lRow = .Range("U" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Identify rows which are blank
        For i = 2 To lRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i)) = 0 Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Delete blank rows
        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey!! Thank you so much, I wasn't ignoring you I have replied :) and really thanks because you understood what I was looking for!! This really helps me a lot! It works really well

Comment: No worries. BTW my curiosity is really troubling me... :P I have a question for you. How much time was it taking earlier and how much time is it taking now to process 100k of data?

Comment: hehe your code takes just a few seconds and mine is like maybe more than 10 mins but my feeling is like hour :D

Comment: Yes heaven, really save my time :)

Comment: Nicely done and almost identical to my own effort. Primary difference was that I sorted out the blanks rather than collect into a union and delete them. I find that faster than deleting discontiguous rows.

Comment: @Jeeped: Yeah I am sure that would be more faster!

Comment: I wonder if there are any ways possibly to convert this code to use it on google sheets? I heard that App-Script is based on javascript not vba.

Answer (score 1):

Modest code refactoring :-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub D()
    Dim earlyDay As Date
    earlyDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("u:u"))
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng_2Del As Range    '
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "U").Value = earlyDay Then
            Select Case Cells(i, "S").Value
                Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                    'Cells(i, "U").EntireRow.Delete
                    Set rng_2Del = App_Union(rng_2Del, Cells(i, "U"))    '
            End Select
        Else
            Select Case Cells(i, "S").Value
                Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                Case Else
                    'Cells(i, "S").EntireRow.Delete
                    Set rng_2Del = App_Union(rng_2Del, Cells(i, "U"))    '
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
    If Not rng_2Del Is Nothing Then rng_2Del.EntireRow.Delete '
End Sub

Public Function App_Union(rng_union As Range, _
                          ByVal rng As Range) _
                          As Range    ' InExSu
    If Not rng_union Is Nothing Then
        Set rng_union = Application.Union(rng_union, rng)
    Else
        Set rng_union = rng
    End If
    Set App_Union = rng_union
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works really really fast, Amazing what you guys have done :)

Comment: I wonder if there are any ways possibly to convert this code to use it on google sheets? I heard that App-Script is based on javascript not vba.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's much faster to delete rows in a single operation than one-by-one:

EDIT: seems like you have more than two days' of data...

```
Sub D()
    Dim earlyDay As Date, sht As Worksheet, rngDel As Range
    Dim m, theDay as Date

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    earlyDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(sht.Range("u:u"))

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        theDay = sht.Cells(i, "U").Value
        m = Application.Match(sht.Cells(i, "S").Value, _
                              Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), 0)

        If (theDay = earlyDay And Not IsError(m)) Or _
           (theDay = earlyDay+1 And IsError(m))Then 

             BuildRange rngDel, sht.Cells(i, "U")

        End If

    Next i

    'delete any flagged rows
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

'build a range from two ranges
Sub BuildRange(rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If Not rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    Else
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! I have just tried your code. it works pretty fast but the result just appears all data from the early day only, data from another day was all deleted.

Comment: Rows which don't match "earlyDay" should only be deleted when Col S isn't in your list of values.   Isn't that the logic in your original code?

Comment: (Column S) have some values which match earlyDay (Column 
U) should be deleted (keep other data) and then select the same values from laterDay (Delete other data from laterDay), Sorry if I don't explain it clearly.

Comment: My logic matches your posted code: I assumed it was just a performance problem you were having.  If the logic needs to be different then you should edit your post to explain exactly what logic you want to use.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my logic. I'm not sure if I can explain it more clearly or worse :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)'s response but using a 'helper' column and sorting to remove the rows.

```
Option Explicit

Sub D2()


    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lc As Long, edt As Long, vals As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

        edt = Application.Min(.Range("U:U"))
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'store worksheet values in array
        vals = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Offset(0, lc - 21)).Value
        'vals = .CurrentRegion.Cells.Offset(1, 0).Value

        'add a sorting counter
        lc = UBound(vals, 2) + 1
        ReDim Preserve vals(LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1), _
                            LBound(vals, 2) To lc)
        For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            vals(i, lc) = i
        Next i

        'clear array values
        For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            If vals(i, 21) = edt Then
                Select Case UCase(vals(i, 19))
                    Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                        For j = LBound(vals, 2) To UBound(vals, 2): vals(i, j) = vbNullString: Next j
                End Select
            Else
                Select Case UCase(vals(i, 19))
                    Case "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
                    Case Else
                        For j = LBound(vals, 2) To UBound(vals, 2): vals(i, j) = vbNullString: Next j
                End Select
            End If
        Next i

        With .Cells(2, "A").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2))

            'return values to worksheet
            .Value = vals

            'sort on the additional column
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(lc), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo

        End With

        'clear the sorting index column
        .Cells(1, lc).EntireColumn.Clear

    End With

    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jeeped for your help, really appreciate it. :)