# VBA delete multiple row in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this code, how can I make it do delete multiple row of number? Should I use "And" function ?

Thanks

```
Sub remove_rows()

    Dim rad As Integer
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet

    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Export Worksheet")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Which row do u want to start with?
    rad = 1

    'Loop row that delete all row in Sheet1 that contain number 2265174

    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(rad, 1)) = True
        If Sheet1.Cells(rad, 1).Value = "2265174" Then
            Rows(rad).Delete
            rad = rad - 1
        End If
        rad = rad + 1

    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple row of number" ?

Comment: Why not just `Filter` Column A on `2265174`, and `Delete` the results?

Comment: I mean that I want to filter after 150BL then delete few row like "2265174" and "1545478" and so on

Comment: When deleting rows, it's recommended to start at the bottom and work your way up. Also, you may what to try @Chronocidal's suggestion, or you can use `.Find()` to find and delete each row with your (no longer) desired text.

Comment: Change `If Sheet1.Cells(rad, 1).Value = "2265174" Then` to `If Sheet1.Cells(rad, 1).Value = "2265174" Or Sheet1.Cells(rad,1).Value = "other value" Then`

Comment: btw², `Sheet1` is very likely the codename of your first worksheet. You shouldn't use it as a variable.

Comment: btw³, you might be interested in a very fast row deletion method detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578570).

Comment: btw, `"2265174"` is not the same as `2265174`. If you have true numbers on your worksheet, they will **not** be equal to a string that looks like them.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub remove_rows()

    Dim rad As Long, rrad As Long
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet

    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Export Worksheet")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Which row do u want to start with?
    rrad = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop row that delete all row in Sheet1 that contain number 2265174

    For rad = rrad To 1 Step -1
        If Sheet1.Cells(rad, 1).Text = "2265174" Then
            Rows(rad).Delete
        End If
    Next rad

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Note:**

- use `Long` rather than `Integer`
- run the loop **backwards**
- use `.Text` to catch both numeric and text values